# Limit number of thread in Play 2.1 framework

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.1

I am using Play 2.1 with Scala to run several tests continuously.
I am doing a `Future.traverse(tests)(test => Future(runTest(test))`.

I want to limit the number of tests running in parallel so I want to limit the number of threads in the default dispatcher.

I tried to put

```
play {
  akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in the `application.conf` but it seems it doesn't have any effect (when I run the program there still is one thread per core). The `application.conf` is correctly read for other play settings.

I tried to get rid of the play{} surrounding it but it changes nothing.

I tried different imports of executions contexts with no success:

```
//import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
```

When I run the application I get this message so it seems that it is the default dispatcher which is used:

```
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
```

Does someone have an idea why I can't configure the default dispatcher?

Thank you!

List of threads :

```
main
Reference Handler
Finalizer
Signal Dispatcher
FSEvent thread
Attach Listener
play-scheduler-1
Timer-0
com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer
BoneCP-keep-alive-scheduler
BoneCP-max-alive-scheduler
BoneCP-pool-alive-scheduler
application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
application-scheduler-1
ForkJoinPool-3-worker-1
default-scheduler-1
default-scheduler-1
default-scheduler-1
default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3
default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3
default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5
default-pinned-dispatcher-4
play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4
Timer-1
Timer-3
Timer-4
Hashed wheel timer #1
Hashed wheel timer #2
Hashed wheel timer #3
AsyncHttpClient-Reaper
AsyncHttpClient-Reaper
AsyncHttpClient-Reaper
default-pinned-dispatcher-4
default-pinned-dispatcher-4
New I/O boss #35
New I/O boss #44
```

And 8 `play-internal-execution-context-` (1 to 8)

And 8 `iteratee-execution-context-` (1 to 8)

And 62 `New I/O worker #` (1 to 62)

Comment: Attach a list of threads?

Comment: Ya, can you attach something (a screenshot maybe) showing the complete list of threads running in your JVM when you run your test?  There are probably multiple `ExecutionContexts` running in your JVM...

Comment: I just added a list of threads. I am running on a Intel i7 so I have 8 cores (and I believe the default value for akka is one thread per core).

Comment: I see two threads for `play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher`, so things seem to be working correctly no?

Comment: No they're not that what's weird. I still have 8 tests running in parallel with that configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you have forgotten is `parallelism-min` which defaults to 8. But before you go and change that one please consider not using the default dispatcher for this purpose: restricting it to two threads may well break the system. I’d recommend [configuring a specific dispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0-RC1/scala/dispatchers.html) to be used for your futures.

Comment: I already tried to set the parallelism-min at a lower value and it changed nothing. I had no more luck with a specific dispatcher, the settings were also ignored.
I finally used schedules to executes tests in parallel.